# Issues deleting Google Admin account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I'm following [Google's instructions](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F9468554%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_event=welcome&assistant_id=gsuitedomainchange-jchbhk&product_context=9468554&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a); attempting to delete an admin account.

I'm currently unable to delete as:

> You have active projects in Google Cloud Platform. You need to delete all GCP projects before you can delete this account. Learn more

I open GCP under the only organization I have in the account and run:

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/123 --asset-types=cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/Project
```

123 changed for my organization number. This returns a number of projects created by apps script, all of which are shown as "state: DELETE_REQUESTED".

I have never configured any "Access Context Manager policies" and all subscriptions are canceled.

Looking through GCP > IAM and admin > Asset Inventory, all projects made by apps script are again shown as "DELETE_REQUESTED".

I ran a number of scripts and have found many other users struggling to find the source of the issue.

Is there anything related to apps script that I have missed? [There are a number of IAM policies related to apps script](https://gyazo.com/a20cf149d45d68d43c1108fcc9576cca), could this cause the active project issue?

Comment: Projects are not deleted for 30 days. You might need to wait for the projects to complete the delete cycle. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects#lifecyclestate  and https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6251787?hl=en#zippy=%2Cshut-down-a-project

Comment: Have you checked if there is anything listed in the [Cloud Resource Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager)?